# Modify multiple elements of a slice/collection at the same time

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<Vec<T>>` (I know it's not ideal; it's from a library). I want to look at pairs of `Vec`s in the outer vec and push to each of them, something like this:

```rust
let mut foo = vec![
    vec![1, 2, 3],
    vec![4, 5, 6],
    vec![7, 8, 9],
];

for i in foo.len() {
    let a = foo.get_mut(i - 1).unwrap();
    let b = foo.get_mut(i).unwrap(); // Does not work

    let val = 2; // Some computation based on contents of a & b

    a.push(val);
    b.insert(0, val);
}
```

Of course, this fails to compile:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `foo` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> foo.rs:6:17
   |
5  |         let a = foo.get_mut(i - 1).unwrap();
   |                 --- first mutable borrow occurs here
6  |         let b = foo.get_mut(i).unwrap(); // Does not work
   |                 ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
10 |         a.push(val);
   |         - first borrow later used here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

It's a similar pattern to the `std::slice::window()` method, but as far as I can tell you can't get *any* mutable items in that.

Is there a way to do this that makes the borrow checker happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this kind of mutation of different parts of a single object at the same time requires `unsafe`. There really isn't a general way for the compiler to tell that you're really accessing *disjoint* parts of the object.

However, in this case, there's a simple encapsulation that should work for your usage. The slice method [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) enables you to get mutable slices of two halves of a mutable slice.

```
let mut foo = vec![
    vec![1, 2, 3],
    vec![4, 5, 6],
    vec![7, 8, 9],
];

for i in 1..foo.len() {
    //   ^^^  note the change
    let (first_half, second_half) = foo.split_at_mut(i);

    // now `first_half` is `foo[0..i]`
    // `second_half` is `foo[i..]`
    let a = first_half.last_mut().unwrap();
    let b = second_half.first_mut().unwrap();

    let val = 2; // Some computation based on contents of a & b

    a.push(val);
    b.insert(0, val);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4f4d96d2537de9e963a291da6a82f806)

You may be able to avoid this completely by holding off on the mutable borrow until you actually mutate the vectors.

```
let mut foo = vec![
    vec![1, 2, 3],
    vec![4, 5, 6],
    vec![7, 8, 9],
];

for i in 1..foo.len() {
    // this could equally be written
    // let a = &foo[i - 1];
    let a = foo.get(i - 1).unwrap();
    let b = foo.get(i).unwrap();

    // This probably doesn't need mutable access, right?
    let val = 2; // Some computation based on contents of a & b

    // now borrow again, but this time mutate.
    foo[i - 1].push(val);
    foo[i].insert(0, val);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d5d3444bbf995f975dfb7fcd553a0a32)

Comment: Please search for existing questions with the answer you propose before answering. There's no need to duplicate this kind of common question and answer many times across Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) to get two disjoint mutable partitions of a slice. So you could do this:

```
let (a,b) = foo.split_at_mut(i);
let a = a.last_mut().unwrap();
let b = b.first_mut().unwrap();
```

Comment: Please search for existing questions with the answer you propose before answering. There's no need to duplicate this kind of common question and answer many times across Stack Overflow.